# Do I need a MVC UpdatePanel?

Tags: html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, updatepanel

I have an MVC web app with a search page, on this search page I have my own search section and below this I have a ASPxGridview - provided by DevExpress that displays the results when fetched from the server.

At the moment when the results come back, the whole page refreshes and does the whole page load life cycle but I only really need to refresh the grid. I believe I need an `updatepanel` if this was web app non MVC application but is this available in MVC? Or is there a a better way to do what I want now?

Many thanks.

Gridview action HTML

```
// Guessing I will need a updatepanel or something here?

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @if(Request.HttpMethod.Equals("GET",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
               @Html.Action("search");
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You can simply use jQGrid to load your search result, and periodically you can make ajax calls (to WebAPI) to refresh your grid.

Comment: Whose idea was it to use devexpress?

Comment: companies - shame I am not a project manager or a senior yet lol

Comment: When you get there, ban all devexpress :)